# How To Find The Longest Odd Sum Sub-Array In A Given Integer Array? (In The Most Efficient Way)

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

The problem: you need to find the longest sub-array with odd sum in a given integers array but both time complexity and space auxiliary should be the best.

I have tried traversing the array with a while loop and two variables for the indexes (low, high while(low <= high)...) but I haven't got good answers every time...

I have tried this: (sum is the total sum of the array)

```
while (low <= high) {

            if((sum - a[low]) % 2 != 0)
                return (high - low);

            else if((sum - a[high]) % 2 != 0)
                return (high - low);

            else{
                if((sum - a[low]) % 2 == 0){
                    sum -= a[low];
                    low++;
                }

                if((sum - a[high]) % 2 == 0){
                    sum -= a[high];
                    high--;
                }
            }
        }
```

For `{2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}` I would expect output of 5
but I'm getting 2

Comment: Either you missunderstood the problem, or your input sample is wrong

Comment: 1+2+2+2+2 = 9 (odd) and the length 5.

Comment: @NiVeR Edited, I didn't saw it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If whole array is odd then you got it.
2. If it is even you need to find even number closest to end of array.

   - If this number is close to start, then result is subaray from next position to end
   - if this number is close to end, then result is subaray from start to this number (excluding number itself).

Comment: What if the sub-array is in the middle of the array? what if it is like the input I gave? I am not sure if it covers every case

Comment: It can't be in the middle. Imagine it is, then sum of adjacent element either odd or even, If it even we add both element to subarray, otherwise one of them is even and we add it to subarray. We can do it until we meet border on one side or another.

Comment: Case you present will work fine. it will find both `1` as closest to border, but first `1` is closer so result will be `1, 2, 2, 2, 2` as you expect.

Comment: perhaps I haven't understood you well... But For ```{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2}``` It wont work, right?

Comment: This array is already odd, so by first line in my message it is answer you need.

Comment: thanks! can you explain the logic behind your method? what if the input is : ```{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}```, how can you apply your method there?

Comment: As I explain before result array should touch at least one end, so we will remove elements from end until result is odd, If we remove even number array remains even, so we will remove numbers until we remove odd one which turns result to even, basicaly searching for closest odd number. Same goes for start. Then we have to choose which result is longer. It is one in which we removed less elements. In your example two odd number closest to end is `1`, but last one is closer, so we get subarray  `2, 1, 2, 2` as result (from start to last `1` not including it).